# How to detect when a process/ thread is waiting for user input

Tags: unix, process, window, jna

Is there a way to detect when a windows process is waiting for user input.

For instance, when you click on a particular program it loads, in this case the program's process is probably in loading state rite?

what happens when the program is fully loaded and is waiting for user input to procedure to next step. Is there a way to detect this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`WaitForInputIdle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a handle to a process. it will suspend execution until the program completes its initialization and is waiting for user input with no input pending.

Comment: It does not return any boolean values, so how can i detect whether the process provided is waiting for user input?

Comment: @Paktrick: It returns `0` for success, `WAIT_FAILED` or `WAIT_TIMEOUT` otherwise (the latter only possible if timeout wasn't `INFINITE`).

Comment: so if the output is 0, this should mean the process provided is loaded?

Comment: hey is it possible to pass process id instead of handle? because i have to map this functions in jna. java native access

Comment: @Paktrick: You should be able to get a handle via [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx). Don't forget to close it later with `CloseHandle` though